# How to stub Date.today.strftime in rspec 3?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I have the following code:

```
  def when_to_change
    year, month = Date.today.strftime("%Y %m").split(' ').map {|v| v.to_i}
    if month < 9
      year + 2
    else 
      year + 3
    end
  end
```

And I try to stub it in my spec in the following way:

```
  it 'when current month at the of a year' do
    allow(Date.today).to receive(:strftime).with('%Y %m').and_return('2015 10')
    expect(@car.when_to_change).to eq(2018)
  end

  it 'when current month earlier than september' do 
    allow(Date.today).to receive(:strftime).with('%Y %m').and_return('2015 07')
    expect(@car.when_to_change).to eq(2017)
  end
```

When I try to run specs it doesn't look that way. What am I doing wrong?

I use rspec `v3.3.2`

`ANSWER`

Since `Date.today` returns new object every method call, this can be done in the following way:

```
  it 'when current month earlier than september' do 
     allow(Date).to receive(:today).and_return(Date.new(2015, 7, 19))
     expect(@car.when_to_change).to eq(2017)
  end
```

thank you to @DmitrySokurenko for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.today` always return new objects. Stub the `today` at first.

I mean that:

```
>> Date.today.object_id
=> 70175652485620
>> Date.today.object_id
=> 70175652610440
```

So when you call the `today` next time, that's a different object.

Thus either stub the `Date.today` to return some fixed date, either change your code to use something like `SomeHelper.today` which will always return the same date in test environment.

Comment: I understood what you said, but I haven't came up with any working way to do this. For now I tried `allow(Date).to receive(:today).and_return(2015, 7, 19)`, but this doesn't work. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Create some date: `the_today = Date.new(Date.new(2015, 11, 19)); allow(Date).to receive(:today).and_return(the_today)`, and then stub everything you need on it.

Comment: why do I need nest `Date.new` like you do  `Date.new(Date.new(2015, 11, 19))` ?

Comment: oh, sorry that's a typo, sure there should be only one `Date.new`

Answer (score 3):

I think [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) would be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Timecop to do that. Rails already has a similar thing built-in:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb
config.include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers
```

And then:

```
travel_to(Date.parse('2015-10-01')) do
  expect(@car.when_to_change).to eq(2018)
end
```